# How to have git repository in NFS partition and working-tree in local partition?

Tags: git, unix

My home directory is in a remotely-mounted NFS partition on a file-server and is routinely backed-up.  I would like to have my project's git repository be under my home directory (so that it's backed-up) but I would like my working-tree to be in a local disk partition of my workstation (so that building is fast).  The local disk partition isn't backed-up.

Any ideas on how to do this?  I know that I can clone the NFS repository and push to it, but that seems like unnecessary overkill.

Could it be as simple as creating a .git symbolic link in the local partition to the .git directory in the remote NFS partition?

Comment: An alternative to making .git a symbolic link is to make a regular file named .git with contents: "gitdir: /p/a/t/h/.git".  AFAIK, this is undocumented behavior and therefore subject to change.

Comment: Thanks for this question (and the answers), I always wanted to try this ... in my case the *local* partition would be the `/tmp/` directory, meaning it can get deleted at any time (between my sessions). So I would need a way to restore it from the repository easily. I'll try the suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create your Git repo with:

- the working tree being a current path on the local disk partition
- but the [`.git` dir](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git-core/docs/) being specified with `--git-dir=<path>` or `$GIT_DIR` environment variable and referring to a path within your (backed-up) home directory.

The [`git init`](http://www.kernel.org/pub//software/scm/git-core/docs/git-init.html) command takes into account the `$GIT_DIR` environment variable:

> If the `$GIT_DIR` environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of `./.git` for the base of the repository.

---

Alternatively, you can create your repo in your home dir, but add the following `git config`:

```
core.worktree
```

> Set the path to the root of the work tree.
>   This can be overridden by the `GIT_WORK_TREE` environment variable and the `--work-tree` command line option.
>   It can be an absolute path or a relative path to the `.git` directory, either specified by `--git-dir` or `GIT_DIR`, or automatically discovered.
>   If `--git-dir` or `GIT_DIR` are specified but none of `--work-tree`, `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `core.worktree` is specified, the current working directory is regarded as the root of the work tree.
>
> Note that this variable is honored even when set in a configuration file in a "`.git`" subdirectory of a directory, and its value differs from the latter directory (e.g. "`/path/to/.git/config`" has `core.worktree` set to "`/different/path`"), which is most likely a misconfiguration.
>   Running git commands in "`/path/to`" directory will still use "`/different/path`" as the root of the work tree and can cause great confusion to the users.

---

The OP adds:

> Could it be as simple as creating a .git symbolic link in the local partition to the .git directory in the remote NFS partition?

At least, with **settings** (like `git-dir`, or `core.worktree`), that allows to achieve the same effect without relying on the OS specific features like symbolic link (which is not available on every OS)

---

Update 2018 (8 years later): [Tom Russell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1609153/tom-russell) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211003/how-to-have-git-repository-in-nfs-partition-and-working-tree-in-local-partition/2211134#comment83065630_2211134):

> It appears that the `--separate-git-dir` flag is now used to point to `.git/` on the NFS server when initializing the repository on the local workstation (NFS client).
>   Subsequent behavior is odd, though: Changes committed on the NFS client don't automatically propagate to the server, requiring a `git checkout -- <file>` on the server.
>
> I subsequently figured out that a `git reset --hard` in the server repo after a commit in the client repo (or vice-versa) is the easiest way to bring a working directory up to date.

Comment: @Bombe: "wording improved" indeed, thank you ;) (improvement done in the true spirit of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38242/full-time-dedicated-editors-on-so/38244#38244)

Comment: could the git-dir alternative you posted, be a solution to distribute multimedia (binary) content using git over to remote Android devices where I can't install Git?

Comment: @microspino: I don't have experience in this kind of environment, but this is certainly worth a try.

Comment: It appears that the `--separate-git-dir` flag is now used to point to `.git/` on the NFS server when initializing the repository on the local workstation (NFS client). Subsequent behavior is odd, though: Changes committed on the NFS client don't automatically propagate to the server, requiring a `git checkout -- <file>` on the server.

Comment: @TomRussell Strange. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC Nice. I subsequently figured out that a `git reset --hard` in the server repo after a commit in the client repo (or vice-versa) is the easiest way to bring a working directory up to date.

Comment: @TomRussell OK makes sense. Maybe a push-to-deploy would avoid that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030236/6309

Answer (score 4):

Create your repo in your home directory as usual, then on your fast local disk, use the script `git-new-workdir` (on my box, under `/usr/share/doc/git-core/contrib/workdir`).  It's not a part of the git core; it's a contributed script but your distro's git package may have installed it.  Usage is:

```
git-new-workdir <repository> <new_workdir>
```

This will create a new, distinct working directory that is linked to your original repository.

Comment: Fantastic solution!

Comment: A couple of caveats: After committing a change in the working directory, the other/remote directory can be brought up to date with a `git reset --hard`. Also, changes staged in one directory won't be reflected in the other.

Answer (score 3):

You can move your .git directory to a remote share, and then you can replace it with a file called '.git', containing 'gitdir: '. It **is** documented in repository layout help page (eg. git help repository-layout).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by overkill, but my suggestion would be to go ahead and have a clone in NFS and push to it.

You can set up a post-commit hook that does a `git push --mirror my-nfs-thing` and not have to even think about it.

Most importantly, you'll always have fast, reliable access to the repository data (without the fear of losing data to system failures, etc...).