# Git push to checkout?

Tags: git

I want to push my files directly to my web server. I added the server as `testing`and tried

```
git push testing
```

but I get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816369/git-push-error-remote-rejected-master-master-branch-is-currently-checked-o). The solution to make a bare repository works but I want the files to be checked out automaticly. I found this [script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279169/deploy-a-project-using-git) but that did not change anything.

I can transfer changes over a third bare repository but that just takes to long:

```
client:
git commit -m "test" -a
git push origin
<password>

server:
git pull origin/master
```

**Update (2)**

I created on the server a new branch `git branch testing`.

Also on the server I created `.git/hooks/post-update` an added:

```
echo "a" >> /home/pi/log
git update-server-info
git stash
git merge testing >> /home/pi/log
```

On the client I run

```
git push testing HEAD:testing
```

Now my `/home/pi/log` contains:

```
a
Updating ae2f44b..04753a9
Fast-forward
 application/views/main/index.php |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

But the file did not change. What could still be wrong?

Comment: at least combine fetch+merge in a pull; the script should work, either you are doing it wrong or you should be able to debug things (add logging your hook to see why it breaks? what version of git?)

Comment: I added `echo "test" > /home/pi/test` at the top `.git/hooks/post-update` and get nothing.

Comment: Did you do the chmod (for the correct user; consider chmod a+x)? What did you name the script exactly? Is the filesystem mounted noexec? (if anyone of these fixes it, I'll post it as an answer :))

Comment: Ok, the script get's executed but I did not find the error in the script. I will try Simons solution.

Comment: After editing a few times this is a new question now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228921/git-post-update-script-does-not-work

Comment: Note: recent Git (2.4.0+, May 2015) allows for pushing to a checked out branch now. See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30030236/6309).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now how ["push-to-deploy" (git 2.4, May 2015)](https://github.com/blog/1994-git-2-4-atomic-pushes-push-to-deploy-and-more), which improves on ["push-to-checkout" (Git 2.3, February 2015)](https://github.com/blog/1957-git-2-3-has-been-released).

See "[Deploy a project using Git push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28381235/6309)" for a concrete example.

In short, you can push directly to a checked out branch (with caveats).
See [commit 4d7a5ce](https://github.com/gitster/git/commit/4d7a5ceacc97e69c4ab5e1543f61fafafb963a9c)

---

Update: With Git 2.30 (Q1 2021), you now have a sample '`push-to-checkout`' hook, that performs the same as what the built-in default action does.

See [commit e632c46](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e632c464d5dbbda72ae370ff6e9cbe31c01b0bb0) (15 Oct 2020) by [Adam Spiers (`aspiers`)](https://github.com/aspiers).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit df7f850](https://github.com/git/git/commit/df7f850a851a0423defe600bafc24bd2d8f57dda), 02 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`hook`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e632c464d5dbbda72ae370ff6e9cbe31c01b0bb0): add sample template for `push-to-checkout`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Adam Spiers</sup>

> The template is a more-or-less exact translation to shell of the C code for the default behaviour for git's push-to-checkout hook defined in the `push_to_deploy()` function in [`builtin/receive-pack.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e632c464d5dbbda72ae370ff6e9cbe31c01b0bb0/builtin/receive-pack.c), to serve as a convenient starting point for modification.
>
> It also contains relevant text extracted from the git-config(1) and githooks(5) man pages.

That is:

> ### An example hook script to update a checked-out tree on a git push.

> This hook is invoked by `git-receive-pack` when it reacts to `git push` and updates reference(s) in its repository, and when the push tries to update the branch that is currently checked out and the `receive.denyCurrentBranch` configuration variable is set to `updateInstead`.
>
> By default, such a push is refused if the working tree and the index
> of the remote repository has any difference from the currently
> checked out commit; when both the working tree and the index match
> the current commit, they are updated to match the newly pushed tip
> of the branch.
>
> This hook is to be used to override the default
> behaviour; however the code below reimplements the default behaviour
> as a starting point for convenient modification.
>
> The hook receives the commit with which the tip of the current
> branch is going to be updated:
>
> ```
> commit=$1
> ```
>
> It can exit with a non-zero status to refuse the push (when it does
> so, it must not modify the index or the working tree).
>
> ```
> die () {
>    echo >&2 "$*"
>    exit 1
> }
> ```
>
> Or it can make any necessary changes to the working tree and to the
> index to bring them to the desired state when the tip of the current
> branch is updated to the new commit, and exit with a zero status.
>
> For example, the hook can simply run `git read-tree -u -m HEAD "$1"`
> in order to emulate `git fetch` that is run in the reverse direction
> with `git push`, as the two-tree form of `git read-tree -u -m` is
> essentially the same as `git switch` or `git checkout` that switches
> branches while keeping the local changes in the working tree that do
> not interfere with the difference between the branches.
>
> The below is a more-or-less exact translation to shell of the C code
> for the default behaviour for git's `push-to-checkout` hook defined in
> the `push_to_deploy()` function in `builtin/receive-pack.c`.
>
> Note that the hook will be executed from the repository directory,
> not from the working tree, so if you want to perform operations on
> the working tree, you will have to adapt your code accordingly, e.g.
> by adding "`cd ..`" or using relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot push to a branch that is checked out, because the branch pointer is used to track the working directory state.

Instead, push to a different branch, then, from the push hook script, merge that branch into your working directory; this merge is then executed as a fast-forward as long as there were no local changes.

Comment: Ok, I tried that (see update) but how do I push into this new branch?

Comment: There is an error in your script: `exec` will replace the current shell process with the command, so only the first command is run.

Comment: I fixed the script, added logging and it looks good but still does nothing. See my update(2)

Comment: I hate answers like this. don't be lazy and include the codes please/.