# git post-update script does not work

Tags: git, bash

After editing my [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227282/git-push-to-checkout) a few times, I make a new one because it is a new question now.

In `.git/hooks/post-update` I have:

```
echo "a" >> /home/pi/log
git update-server-info
git stash
git merge testing >> /home/pi/log
```

To make an automated checkout. So I run on the client:

```
git push testing HEAD:testing
```

Now my `/home/pi/log` contains:

```
a
Updating ae2f44b..04753a9
Fast-forward
 application/views/main/index.php |    2 +-
 1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

But the file did not change!

```
$ git merge testing
Already up-to-date.
```

If I remove the script, make the push and run `git stash`, `git merge testing` it works.

**Update**

For testing I changed a number in a file from 17 to 20. I can see the right file version if I run

```
git show application/views/main/index.php
```

but

```
vim application/views/main/index.php
```

Still contains the old number. But git claims the file is updated:

```
$ git merge testing
Already up-to-date.
```

Comment: Can you check the environment variables GIT_DIR, GIT_WORK_TREE and GIT_INDEX in the script's execution context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use `post-receive` as Alex pointed out. Also you need run `unset GIT_DIR` at the top of your script.

On the server I have created a second branch and switched to it:

```
$ git branch
  master
* testing
```

My `.git/hooks/post-receive` now looks like this:

```
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git merge master
```

On the client I run `git push`.

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT**

It looks like [this is your problem](http://longair.net/blog/2011/04/09/missing-git-hooks-documentation/):

> ```
>  pre-receive
>  update
>  post-receive
>  post-update
> ```
>
> These hooks can be run either in a bare or a non-bare repository.  In both
>   cases, the current working directory will be the git directory.  So, if this
>   is a bare repository called "/src/git/test.git/", that will be the current
>   working directory -- if this is a non-bare repository and the top level of
>   the working tree is "/home/mark/test/" then the current working directory
>   will be "/home/mark/test/.git/".
>
> In both cases, the following environment variable is set:
>   `GIT_DIR` is set to ‘.’
>
> With a working tree, this is unexpectedly awkward, as described in Chris
>   Johnsen’s answer that I linked to earlier.  If only `GIT_DIR` is set then
>   this comment from the git man page applies:
>
> Note: If `--git-dir` or `GIT_DIR` are specified but none of `--work-tree,`
>   `GIT_WORK_TREE` and `core.worktree` is specified, the current working
>   directory is regarded as the top directory of your working tree.
>
> In other words, your working tree will also be the current directory (the
>   ".git" directory), which almost certainly isn’t what you want.

You could try setting `GIT_WORK_TREE=..` or `GIT_WORK_TREE="$GIT_DIR/.."` inside the hook

---

> But the file did not change!

Most likely it did. Perhaps only the lineending did, or there were whitespace changes that are ignored when viewing the diffs, but it did change. Git knows, because the SHA1 sum of the file content changed.

Are you using windows on either end?

Windows has a tendency to mess with the line-endings. See the core.autocrlf and related options:

- [Why should I use core.autocrlf=true in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git)

Comment: Yes, the client is on windows. How can this be an issue here? Why does it work manually but not with the script?

Comment: I am counting up a number in a file. 17 must be different from 20 regardless some line endings or whitespaces. Doesn't it?

Comment: It is always PEBCAK! I ask because I don't see how your answer is related to the question. I don't have trouble with line endings and even if there where all messed up it would no explain why I commit the string "20" and the updated file on the server contains "17".

Comment: Added relevant info to the answer

Comment: I think that must be it but I did not get it to work. In the other post-update script they use `export GIT_DIR=$(cd $GIT_DIR; pwd)` and `GIT_WORK_TREE=${GIT_WORK_TREE-..}` but that did not work either. I don't have the time to play around with git right now. But I will try this again in a few days...

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the `post-receive` hook instead? Maybe something is not yet finished in the `post-update` and that is why the merge is not working.

Also I think you should try to include `git reset --hard` in the script so that the git status is synchronised with the file system.