# Git post-update hook not running

Tags: git, githooks

First of all, I am aware there are many similar questions out there, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9228921/git-post-update-script-does-not-work).

However, usually there are 2 main problems:

1.The hook file is not executable - checked. Here is the result of my `ls -l`:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  314 Sep 29 17:18 post-update
```

2.git working directory not set -checked. Here is my post-update hook script:

```
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
echo "testing"
chmod -R 755 path/to/my/target/directory
```

And, even if my path is wrong, I would expect seeing the word `testing` when I do `git pull`, but nothing happens. I guess this means my post-update hook script is not run? What have I missed to make it running?

Comment: `post-update` is a hook that's deployed and runs in the remote repository, so `git pull` can't invoke it. If you local repository has `post-update` installed, then a successful push from another repository to the local repository can trigger it.

Comment: @ElpieKay You are right. I should use `post-merge` instead. Mind making it an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score -2):

## **add: add --chmod=+x / --chmod=-x options**

The executable bit will not be detected (and therefore will not be    set) for paths in a repository with `core.filemode` set to false,    though the users may still wish to add files as executable for    compatibility with other users who do have `core.filemode`    functionality.    For example, Windows users adding shell scripts may wish to add them as executable for compatibility with users on non-Windows.

Although this can be done with a plumbing command **(git update-index --add --chmod=+x foo),** teaching the `git-add` **command allows users to set a file executable with a command that they're already familiar with.**