# Is a new repository created on GitHub, a bare repository? Isn't there a terminal on GitHub with which I can check?

Tags: github

Tried running the `--is-bare-repository` command but realized that running it on my cloned copy wasn't right. Is there no way to use the same command on the actual GitHub repository? The repository shows no `.git` file either. Forgive me, but I'm still very new to GitHub and trying to figure out how to use it. The [command bar](https://github.com/blog/1264-introducing-the-command-bar) seems to be only for searching.

Comment: Why does it matter?  Whether something is a bare repo basically just affects what's seen on the local filesystem (and of course, you don't have access to the local filesystem of the Github server...)

Comment: Just wanted to know...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, GitHub repositories created using GitHub web interface ([/new](https://github.com/new)) are bare Git repositories.

Comment: @Oli [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854879/whats-the-difference-between-github-repository-and-git-bare-repository) — Actually, that kinda makes this question a duplicate…

Comment: @grgarside: true, but one additional piece of info my question asks is whether we can use a terminal on the actual GitHub repository (if it makes sense to use one)