# Can't push files to another remote repo

Tags: git, macos, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2

I have a repo on my laptop and I want to push it to a remote repo on AWS EC2. This is how I build this. I upload my laptop repo on github. The repo on the EC2 was cloned from github. But I did a lot of config on the EC2 so I put some file in `.gitignore`. I want to update some my new code on my laptop to EC2 so I want to push the code to repo on EC2 directly.

This is what I did to push:
I used MacOS, and I edit `~/.ssh/config` and add

```
Host Vidaminds_server
Hostname www.vidaminds.com
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/Downloads/Vidaminds.pem
```

And I used this command:

```
git remote add Vidaserver2 Vidaminds_server:~/Vidaminds/.git
git push Vidaserver2 master
```

It shows:

```
shen-3:New Platform shen$ git push -f Vidaserver2 master
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 507 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
To Vidaminds_server:~/Vidaminds/.git
   4cfe6da..7a6a4a8  master -> master
```

The dir on the EC2 is `/home/Vidaminds/` and there is a `.git` file in the folder. After I push it to EC2 my laptop shows it success but I didn't see my file change. I don't know if there is any error what I did.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pushing to the .git folder alone won't update the working tree content  ~/Vidaminds.

On EC2, try (after the push)

```
cd ~/Vidaminds
git checkout -- .
```

In order to force the working tree to reflect the new branch history (assuming here, for instance, that you have pushed `master`)

You could also set up your EC2 repo to [accept a push-to-deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30030236/6309), allowing you to push directly to that non-bare repo.