# can svn and git both separate repositories from working copy?

Tags: git, svn

For various reasons, I need to separate the repository from the working copy onto separate drives, though allow push/pulls to still function normally.

Is this possible in Git?

Is this possible in SVN?

If both- is one more easy-to-do this with than the other?

Just getting started with this, thanks in advance

Comment: Which platform are you dealing with here?

Comment: windows, and I'm most interested in how to do this with SourceTree (git) and TortoiseSVN (svn)

Comment: "various reasons" could you elaborate?

Comment: d'oh, this was a poorly phrased question... I meant to separate the .git/.svn metadata folders out from the working copy, hehe. The reason is essentially that the working copy should not contain those metadata folders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With [git](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/) you can set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable:

  > If the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is set then it specifies a path to use instead of the default .git for the base of the repository. The `--git-dir` command-line option also sets this value.

  For an example, see also this question: [How to have git repository in NFS partition and working-tree in local partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211003/how-to-have-git-repository-in-nfs-partition-and-working-tree-in-local-partition)
- SVN separates repository and working copy by design, as far as I remember; just [initialize](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.create.html) the repo on one location and [checkout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) to another (using a [remote or local URL](http://svnbook.spears.at/en/1.1/ch07s07.html)).

Comment: hmmm, any tips on how to do each of these with SourceTree (git) and TortoiseSVN (svn) ?

Comment: @davidkomer, sorry, I never used those GUIs.

Comment: @davidkomer It's not something you _do_ in Subversion; the repository is _always_ distinct from the working copy. (Note however that Subversion always has working copy metadata (`.svn`) in each working copy directory, which is unavoidable and might be something you also don't want.)